# Scenarios for Indian citizen for missing connecting flight in Doha

Tags: indian-citizens, layovers, qatar-airways, doha

I am an Indian student in Germany. I will be travelling to India via Doha in Qatar Airways. My connection time is 50 minutes. I have read a lot of posts where, in case of any delay or connection missed, Qatar Airways gave transit and accommodation to the concerned passenger. However, the posts I read were from non-Indians. I know that Indians do not get on arrival visa of any kind in Qatar but Qatar Airways website says they would try to get a transit and free accommodation in such a scenario (no nationality mentioned though).

I would like to know if I would be given a transit visa and accommodation on missing the connecting flight since the next flight is 24 hours later. If not transit, would they at least take up responsibility and give free accommodation in the airport hotel itself? Or would they transfer me via some other airline via another route (For example, Sri Lankan Airlines via Colombo or Emirates via Dubai). I am travelling for the first time back home from abroad, sorry if the question sounds very noob-ish.

Comment: It may be noobish but it's a great question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, 50 minutes appears to be a pretty tight connection. While you probably won't miss the flight if you walk quickly through the airport, it's wise to be concerned and to investigate what might happen.

When your first flight ends, let an airline staff member know that you have a short connection. They may be able to help you make it through the airport more quickly to your connecting flight.

In case you miss your connecting flight and it wasn't your fault (incoming flight was late, diverted, long security lines, etc.), then the airline is responsible for rebooking you on a new flight, and providing accommodation if this requires you to have to stay overnight. You may also receive meal vouchers which are good in airport restaurants.

In the case of Qatar, it is possible for you to transit landside if your accommodations are arranged by the airline. [From Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&HEALTH=&page=both&NA=IN&AR=00&EM=DE&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IN&TR=QA&user=QR&subuser=QRBRC):

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>
> - Holders of a prearranged Stopover Paid by Carrier (STPC) issued to those in transit for min. 8 hours and max. 24 hours are permitted to leave the transit area, if holding passports valid for at least 3 months and subject to approval from immigration.

Everyone - including the airlines - hates missed connections, but they do happen, and it's unlikely you *wouldn't* be approved for a landside transit in this case, unless Qatar believed that you were some sort of security threat.

Note that if it's *your* fault that you missed the connecting flight (e.g. you spent an hour in duty free and forgot the time) then the airline has no responsibility to you, and you are responsible for your own accommodations and paying for rebooking the flight.